# How to access value with _ proprieties in click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to access properties and event in the click event in Vue.

This is taken from the row click event so I want to access `_draggableInstance`

How can I access this property from below details?

```
 sender: {…}        ​​
    _cellId: "contactListView_active_cell"        ​​
    _checkBoxSelection: true        ​​
    _clearSortClasses: null        ​​
    _data: Array(147) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]        ​​
    _draggableInstance: {…}
```

Comment: What happens when you use `sender._draggableInstance`?

Comment: yes as you comment it is possible but inside that, there are some function need to call

Comment: What happens when you use `sender._draggableInstance.functionName()`?